# Ubuntu 12.04 Lenovo Thinkpad W530 with Mini Dock Plus Series 3 - No Output via DVI

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, thinkpad, docking

Good afternoon,
  I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W530 with the Quadro K1000m discreet GPU.  I also have a Lenovo Mini Dock Plus Series 3.  This dock has dual DVI output on the back and, according to Lenovo, this laptop + dock combination will allow me to have 3 unique displays (1x LCD panel and 2x DVI).

When I dock my Thinkpad I never get any output through the DVI ports.  The screens flip back to their analogue inputs (connected to another PC).

- In the BIOS I've selected Optimus and OS switching in the Display settings.
- I've installed and configured Bumblebee to use the Nvidia card on demand (by prefixing commands with optirun - example: optirun glxspheres64)

  Is there anything else I need to do or is it simply the case that this dock is not yet supported by Ubuntu?

  Regards

RobC

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found a workaround although it's not ideal.

It so happened that I wanted to rebuild my Ubuntu 12.04 install as I'd got myself into an nvidia driver hell.  I decided to install Ubuntu with the laptop in the dock and the discreet GPU enabled in the BIOS.  This appeared to force Ubuntu to install the nvidia drivers and both of my external DVI displays are now active and I'm running my laptop in triple screen glory.

The downside is that I have to enable the Intel GPU in the BIOS if I want to run my laptop out of the dock and on battery power.  If I leave the discreet GPU enabled then the laptop is constantly freezing.  I suspect a driver update may fix this issue.